# C# - System Data SqlClient SqlException

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlexception

So I am in the midst of debugging a program I have been working on quite sometime that will email the user an email that will the user an email that contains information on an error a client is having trying to get into a mobile app. The problem that I am having is even though I have set the parameter, I am getting the following error message:

> The parameterized query '(@USER_NAME varchar(8000))SELECT USER_NAME, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, L' expects the parameter '@USER_NAME', which was not supplied.

I have never encountered this error before so I am not sure if there is something I am missing in my code or if I just put in the wrong syntax. Below is both the method where the error is happening in and the class that this method uses:

Method:

```
private static MyHomeInformation GetUserDataFromMyHome(string username)
    {
        MyHomeInformation myHomeInformation = null;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MyHomeConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlError = connection.CreateCommand();
            sqlError.CommandText = @"SELECT USER_NAME, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TRAVELER_UID FROM TANDT_PORTAL.dbo.[USER] WHERE USER_NAME = @USER_NAME";
            sqlError.Parameters.Add("@USER_NAME", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);

            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlError.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                myHomeInformation = new MyHomeInformation();
                myHomeInformation.myHomeUserName = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["USER_NAME"]);
                myHomeInformation.myHomeEmail = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["EMAIL"]);
                myHomeInformation.myHomeFirstName = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["FIRST_NAME"]);
                myHomeInformation.myHomeLastName = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["LAST_NAME"]);
                myHomeInformation.myHomeTravelerUID = Utilities.FromDBValue<Guid>(reader["TRAVELER_UID"]);
            }
        }
        return myHomeInformation;
    }
```

Class:

```
class MyHomeInformation
{
    public string myHomeUserName { get; set; }
    public string myHomeEmail { get; set; }
    public string myHomeFirstName { get; set; }
    public string myHomeLastName { get; set; }
    public Guid myHomeTravelerUID { get; set; }  
}
```

Comment: You did not supplied `@USER_NAME` parameter for where clause.

Comment: The `@USER_NAME` parameter is created, but the value is never set.

Comment: You probably want to use `AddWithValue` not `Add` for the parameter

Comment: @Hogan Avoid using AddWithValue(). There are potential performance issues with it.

Comment: @X-TECH in the where clause though I have `USER_NAME` = `@USER_NAME` so aren't I supplying it in the where clause?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - I believe you but I wonder how often it is "visible" relative to the actual DB call.

Comment: @user2580 You need to set value for the parameter `@USER_NAME`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the sqlError.Parameters.Add to **AddWithValue**

```
private static MyHomeInformation GetUserDataFromMyHome(string username)
{
    MyHomeInformation myHomeInformation = null;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MyHomeConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand sqlError = connection.CreateCommand();
        sqlError.CommandText = @"SELECT USER_NAME, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TRAVELER_UID FROM TANDT_PORTAL.dbo.[USER] WHERE USER_NAME = @USER_NAME";
        sqlError.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER_NAME", username); // THIS ROW SHOULD BE UPDATED

        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = sqlError.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            myHomeInformation = new MyHomeInformation();
            myHomeInformation.myHomeUserName = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["USER_NAME"]);
            myHomeInformation.myHomeEmail = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["EMAIL"]);
            myHomeInformation.myHomeFirstName = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["FIRST_NAME"]);
            myHomeInformation.myHomeLastName = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["LAST_NAME"]);
            myHomeInformation.myHomeTravelerUID = Utilities.FromDBValue<Guid>(reader["TRAVELER_UID"]);
        }
    }
    return myHomeInformation;
}
```

Comment: Avoid AddWithValue() in favor of an Add() overload the sets the explicit type of the parameter. AddWithValue() can have parameter type mismatches that result in big performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of the correct way to use the parameters collection add function:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@USER_NAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 8000);
param.Value = "Sam";
sqlError.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Note the setting of the value to Sam.

You could also use the function `AddWithValue` if you don't want to create the param variable. (However,  @JoelCoehoorn will be worried about performance issues - see question comments)

Answer (score 1):

You add your parameter to the call, but give the parameter no value.

change

```
sqlError.Parameters.Add("@USER_NAME", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
```

to

```
sqlError.Parameters.Add("@USER_NAME", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).value = username;
```